# Why my symfony project under www on wamp doesn't run

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have just setup a wamp server on non standard port (80XX), installed pear, download and setup symfony project with this tutorial here:
http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowToInstallSymfonyOnWindowsWithWamp

At final step, since I put it on www\sfproject the page here http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/05-Web-Server-Configuration says that it should now run. But when testing it does only show the files content:

```
apps/        
cache/       
config/      
data/        
lib/         
log/     
plugins/         
symfony  
symfony.bat  
test/    -   
web/
```

What's wrong ?

Update: some people think I have misunderstood config. No as I said I didn't want to configure a virtual domain, I just want it to run under www though it's not secure as they said I don't care it's just for local usage.

That's the problem with these bloated opensource frameworks: documentation, setup of poor quality, nobody really checks.

Comment: Your configuration doesn't seem correct. You should be pointing your web server to the web folder, not to the Symfony project folder directly.

Comment: As I said I didn't want to configure a virtual domain, I just want it to run under www though it's not secure as they said I don't care it's just for local usage.

Comment: In which case, you need to point whatever folder you are using for DocumentRoot at the `web` folder. This is where the front controllers are eg index.php and so on.  Otherwise your setup will not work. Side note: complaining about the framework on SO is not likely to endear people to your cause :-)

Comment: Can you include your config from your `httpd.conf` file

Comment: Well it's a big file. But it's just standard Wamp file I didn't modify it since I don't want to use vhost.

Answer (score 1):

The site probably works when navigating to localhost:80XX/sfproject/web . You can either create a vhost or symlink /Application/MAMP/htdocs to sfproject/web but that's not recommended.